# Nextjs - While Updating/Migrating code to CSS Modules from deprecated packages like @zeit-next/css and @zeit-next/sass, throws strange Error

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, css-modules

updating/migrating code for above mentioned scenario mainly involves(as I know) renaming CSS files to modules and applying styles, to related all of components so far good no error later converting code to CSS modules from then was facing issue/error like "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.", I have checked all imports/export are mentioned correctly still throwing an error and points to some node module file or next\server\pages_document.js, here is snap for reference [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKS1O.png), please help me where actual issue raising, tell me how to make it work properly.[_app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5jDa.png)

_document.js  -->>
`

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en'>
        <Head>
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='57x57' href='/static/apple-icon-57x57.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='60x60' href='/static/apple-icon-60x60.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='72x72' href='/static/apple-icon-72x72.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='76x76' href='/static/apple-icon-76x76.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='114x114' href='/static/apple-icon-114x114.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='120x120' href='/static/apple-icon-120x120.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='144x144' href='/static/apple-icon-144x144.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='152x152' href='/static/apple-icon-152x152.png' />
          <link rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='180x180' href='/static/apple-icon-180x180.png' />
          <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='192x192' href='/static/android-icon-192x192.png' />
          <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='32x32' href='/static/favicon-32x32.png' />
          <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='96x96' href='/static/favicon-96x96.png' />
          <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='16x16' href='/static/favicon-16x16.png' />
          <link rel='icon' href='/static/favicon.ico' />
          <link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json' />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileColor' content='#ffffff' />
          <meta name='msapplication-TileImage' content='/ms-icon-144x144.png' />
          <meta name='theme-color' content='#ffffff' />
          <style>{`body { margin: 0 } `}</style>
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N3G29HD');`
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <noscript>
            <iframe
              title=''
              src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=***-*******'
              height='0'
              width='0'
              style={{ display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
            />
          </noscript>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script
            type='text/javascript'
            src='//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=**-**********'
          ></script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
export default MyDocument;
`
```

Comment: Please use code snippets, do not use images for code.

Comment: The issue is not in your custom `_document`, despite what the error suggests. It's most likely in one of your components. Make sure the exports/imports are all correct.